# UseHiLo EF Core 5 setting value to previous one

Tags: oracle, entity-framework-core, hilo

modelBuilder.HasSequence("SEQ_TEST").IncrementsBy(1);

entity.Property(e => e.TestId)
.HasPrecision(10)
.HasColumnName("TEST_ID")
.ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
.UseHiLo("SEQ_TEST", "SCHEMA_NAME");

I can add 10 rows but for 11th row, its again reverting back to previous TEST_ID resulting in PK violation.
Is there anything that I am missing here ?

Comment: This fixed my issue modelBuilder.HasSequence("SEQ_TEST","SCHEMA_NAME").IncrementsBy(1);

Answer (score 1):

This fixed my issue modelBuilder.HasSequence("SEQ_TEST","SCHEMA_NAME").IncrementsBy(1);